# getParams() with JsonArrayRequest

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

I am trying to get the response from the server based on the data I send it, I am able to get a response from the server, but the server doesn't seem to be receiving the values in the getParams().

```
       String url = "myUrl";
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        schoolContributeList = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray ja) {
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0;i < ja.length();i++) {
                                JSONObject school = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                                String schoolId = school.getString("id");
                                String schoolName = school.getString("name");
                                universityItem schoolItem = new universityItem(schoolName, schoolId);

                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),schoolId , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                schoolContributeList.add(schoolItem);
                                schoolContributeAdapter =  new universityAdapter(getContext(), schoolContributeList);
                                schoolContributeSpinner.setAdapter(schoolContributeAdapter);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) 
            {
                Log.i("error", error.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "no response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), selectedUniversityItem.getmUniversityValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                params.put("schoolUniversity", selectedUniversityItem.getmUniversityValue());
                params.put("key", key);
                return params;
            }

        };
        queue.add(jsonRequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I would suggest in this case is to pass the parameters in the URL of your code and remove the getParams() method.
So, your modified code looks like;

```
 String url = "myUrl";
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    schoolContributeList = new ArrayList<>();
    JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url+"?schoolUniversity="+selectedUniversityItem.getmUniversityValue()+"&key="+key,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray ja) {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0;i < ja.length();i++) {
                            JSONObject school = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                            String schoolId = school.getString("id");
                            String schoolName = school.getString("name");
                            universityItem schoolItem = new universityItem(schoolName, schoolId);

                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),schoolId , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            schoolContributeList.add(schoolItem);
                            schoolContributeAdapter =  new universityAdapter(getContext(), schoolContributeList);
                            schoolContributeSpinner.setAdapter(schoolContributeAdapter);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) 
        {
            Log.i("error", error.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "no response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){


    };
    queue.add(jsonRequest);
```

Hopefully, this will work. Good Luck :)

Comment: This worked perfectly! for now... Hopefully I'll be able to find a more practical solution for future projects, thanks!